# property cannot be found on object

Tags: java, hibernate, thymeleaf

I have two classes in relation `Product.java` and `AdminUser.java`

**Product.java**

```
public class ProducImpl{
     //one to one relation between product and sku
    protected Sku defaultSku;
     @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.Eager,targetEntity=AdminUserImpl.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="PRODUCT_SELLER_XREF", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID",refernecedColumnName="PRODUCT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ADMIN_USER_ID",refernecedColumnName="ADMIN_USER_ID")
    public List<AdminUser> adminUser = new ArrayList<AdminUser>();

    public List<AdminUser> getAdminUser(){
       return adminUser;
     }
     public void setAdminUser(List<AdminUser> adminUser){
      this.adminUser = adminUser;
     } 
   //getters and setter for defaultSku
}
```

**AdminUser.java**

```
 public class AdminUserImpl{
      @Column(name="NAME",nullable="false")
      @Index(name="ADMINUSER_NAME_INDEX",columnNames="NAME")
      protected String name;
           @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.Eager,targetEntity=ProductImpl.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="PRODUCT_SELLER_XREF", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ADMIN_USER_ID",refernecedColumnName="ADMIN_USER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID",refernecedColumnName="PRODUCT_ID")
        public List<Product> product= new ArrayList<Product>();

        public List<product> getProduct(){
           return product;
         }
         public void setProduct(List<AdminUser> product){
          this.product= product;
         } 
        public String getName(){
           return name;
         }
        public void setName(String name){
           this.name=name;
        }
   }
```

In product page I need to show the product details like `product name`, `skucode`,`sellername`, we are using `thymleaf` so, by using `th:object` we are getting `product` object and with the help of product object able to get product details but the problem here is, when I try to get the name of seller which is there in `adminuser` object I am getting an exception saying

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 19): Field or property 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'org.hibernate.internal.PersistantBag'- may not public?
```

**Product.html**

```
<div th:object={$product}>//loading product object
    code : <span th:text=*{defaultSku.id}></span>//getting sku id for product
    brand: <a th:text=*{manufacturer}//getting brand name
    seller: <span th:text=*{adminUser.name}//failing to get seller name
</div>
```

for `defaultSku.id` in `product` object there is a relationship between `product` and `sku` so when I call `defaultSku.id` I am getting `skuid` successfully but when I call `adminUser.name` getting exception anything wrong in the relation? why I am getting that exception? can anyone help me how to solve?

Comment: It really blows my mind.

Comment: You are missing a setter method for Admin user name property. Try to print the admin user name in java and check the logs and tell us what you get.

Comment: @Lucky I have, but forgot to copy paste...

Comment: It seems that `ProductImpl` is returning a list of `AdminUser`s which doesn't have the property `name`. What I also noted is that `AdminUserImpl` is not implementing the `AdminUser` interface.

Comment: You're sure that setProduct accepts a list of AdminUser?

Comment: @UweAllner yeah because when `adminuser` add a `product` records are inserting in to db without any issues, but the problem is I am unable to show the `adminuser` name in front end so that user can able to know who is added which `product`

Comment: I am quite sure that theses snippets won't compile... : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @UweAllner they are compiling fine and I found solution for my problem and the solution is looping through `List` object in the front end.   `seller: <span th:each="adminUsers : *{adminUser}" th:object="*{adminUsers}" th:text=*{name}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the solution for my above problem

**problem**

when I call `seller: <span th:text=*{adminUser.name}`
actually I am getting `adminUser` object in a `List` object without looping it I am trying to access the name of admin user hence it is throwing an exception

**solution**

`seller: <span th:each="adminUsers : *{adminUser}" th:object="*{adminUsers}" th:text=*{name}`